# Python Interactive Interpreter always returns "Invalid syntax" on Windows

Tags: python, windows

I've encountered an extremely confusing problem.  Whatever I type into the Python interpreter returns "Invalid Syntax".  See examples below.  I've tried fooling around with the code page of the prompt I run the interpreter from, but it doesn't seem to help at all.

Furthermore, I haven't been able to find this particular, weird bug elsewhere online.

Any assistance anyone could provide would be lovely.  I've already tried reinstalling Python, but I didn't have any luck - the problem is also there in both 3.13 and 2.7.

Running:
Python version 3.1.3,
Windows XP SP3.

Getting:

```
C:\Program Files\Python31>.\python
Python 3.1.3 (r313:86834, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:53) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>> 2+2
  File "<stdin>", line 1  
    2+2
       ^     
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> x = "Oh, fiddlesticks."  
  File "<stdin>", line 1  
    x = "Oh, fiddlesticks."  
                           ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: have you tried to reinstall python, right?

Comment: Tried reinstalling, as well as using 2.7.  No luck either way.

Comment: You might try downloading fresh copies of the Python installer(s). Also, is it only the Python interactive shell that's broken -- i.e. are you able  to run Python scripts from the OS command line?

Comment: I get it.  It's a trick question.  It's really "guess what non-printing character I'm able to enter along with the newline character."

Comment: @S.Lott: Yeah, but the only reasonable option is \r, and the Windows install should reasonably handle that. :)

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: "but the only reasonable option"... Then it's time to trot out the unreasonable options, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

There is a known problem when running Python interactively and unbuffered, which is scheduled for fixing in 3.2 - and may be backported to older versions, see http://bugs.python.org/issue11098

The nasty thing is, one may be using unbuffered I/O without realising it. In my case (Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916)), I had some time ago set an environment variable such that Python would *always* run unbuffered (on Windows, this is PYTHONUNBUFFERED=YES, or whatever non-empty string substituted for YES) and then forgot about it. Removing the env.var. solved the problem for me.

So it may be worthwhile checking for this environment variable. It's not set by default.

Answer (score 4):

Now that the sample has been cleaned up it appears the problem is with the line termination.

This isn't a solution, but what happens if you create a file `t.py` containing this code, run it, and then type in some text?:

```
import sys; print(repr(sys.stdin.readline()))
```

If you type something like `2+2` then with luck this will show you what the Python interpreter is getting in your example and that in turn might give some clue to the problem.

You can also try this at the command prompt:

```
python -c "import sys; print(repr(sys.stdin.readline()))"
```

This will allow you to type one line and display the details of that one line.

Comment: Ingenious diagnostic technique.  However, the newline is stripped by `input` and `raw_input`.  You'd need to use `sys.stdin.readline()`.

Comment: If it is just a newline it shouldn't be causing the problem, but I still agree that your suggestion sounds better.

Answer (score 0):

Once, in like 2002, I managed to build a version of Python who couldn't run with Windows line-ending. It would give syntax errors like this, pointing at the end of the line. I find this highly unlikely that it is a problem in this case though, especially since you are using the Windows install.

I also had similar problems when I was inadvertently using non-breaking spaces instead of just spaces, but I don't see how that would happen from the prompt, and besides you 2+2 example doesn't use spaces nor quotes which also could be a problem.

What encodings and keyboard settings are you using?

Comment: Keyboard is en-US.  Codepage in cmd defaults to 437 (US).  The localization settings are also en-US.  I'm not sure what data you need beyond this; I don't speak Windows very well...

Comment: @user559217: Well, your problem is "impossible" and can't happen. If you have your pc setup so it can be remote controlled with rdesktop I could take a look at it, just because it's so bizarre. :)

Comment: @user559217: Do you have some fancy "macro" or "hot key" package or some other DOS-isms turned on?  It looks a lot like your "Enter" key is doing more than simply ending the line.

Answer (score 0):

This is a worry:

```
C:\Program Files\Python31>.\python
```

It is never a very good idea to run software with the current directory set to the software installation directory. You run the risk of creating files that interfere with the running of the software. When you start getting bugs and weird behaviour, the consequent thrashing about can get the situation completely out of control.

This is better:

C:\somewhere_else_with_no_spaces>"c:\program files\python31\python"

Best is to keep it out of "program files". Unless I'm misremembering, the suggested installation folder would be `C:\Python31` which is good because you don't need the quotes like you do whenever you use "program files". There is AFAIK no good reason for having software in "program files".

Some diagnostics:

A. open up a Command Prompt window.
B. type this: `dir "c:\program files\python31"`
C. copy/paste the result from step B into an edit of your question i.e. don't put it in a comment.

It would help if you answered (in an edit of your question) the question that somebody asked about keyboard macros ... also consider the possibility of over-smart keyboards, and of having multiple IMEs and not using the "correct" one. Also, is this behaviour happening with any software other than Python?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem even though it might not the same like you, but there's alternative way to diagnostic, you should always set up a history file.

[image]

I find out the reason by `vim` the history file (or you might consider `hexdump -C` in case `vim` doesn't shows the hidden characters):

[image]

According to http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-controls :

> RLM and LRM characters
>
> Two other invisible but non-embedding directional control characters
>   provided by Unicode do not usually have corresponding markup and
>   should be used either in character or escaped form. Note that they are
>   less problematic because they are used singly, not in pairs to delimit
>   ranges of text like the other control characters we have discussed.
>
> ```
> U+200E:   LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK
> U+200F:   RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK
> ```

The reason is because i direct copy/paste from online code(i know it's  dangerous in security though) which contains hidden RLM and LRM characters.