# Python gives "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" under Cygwin but not in CMD, after hitting "return"?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, cygwin

I have used Cygwin for years and recently started using Python. I decided not to use the Cygwin provided Python (for various other issues) and installed a native Windows version. However, when running this version in the Cygwin shell it behaves a bit different than when running on the Windows Command line (CMD). The problem is that hitting "return" when in Cygwin, results in a "SyntaxError", whereas doing the same in CMD, does not. Here's what happens:

**In Cygwin:**

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
  File "<stdin>", line 1

    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> ^Z
```

**In (Win) CMD:**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> ^Z
```

I cannot comprehend what's going on. Any ideas?

PS. I've had python on my machine many times before (including the Cygwin native version), without any problem, but have since removed all those. I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569858/python-interactive-interpreter-always-returns-invalid-syntax-on-windows) post, suggesting that it could have something to do with the character set or end-of-line character...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha! I just found an old latent environment variable: `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` and disabled it, as suggested elsewhere. Now it works. Apparently this is a known Python bug... Another way is to run your python interpreter with: `python -E`, which disables all python related environment variables.