# python keeps reporting "invalid syntax" at end of line via a telnet session

Tags: python, telnet

When opening the python interpreter via a telnet session, every command that is sent is rejected with "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".
How can I send commands via a telnet session sucessfully?

Example: 
starting a server that offers the python interpreter in interactive mode:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:5092 EXEC:'python -i'
```

connecting with telnet and sending a command from the telnet session:

```
>telnet localhost 5092
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
print "test"
```

results on the server side in the following:

```
>socat TCP-LISTEN:5092 EXEC:'python -i' 
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "test"
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I run all this in two separate terminal windows on Mac OS X 10.9.2. Python version 2.7.5.

I found a question describing a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569858/python-interactive-interpreter-always-returns-invalid-syntax-on-windows), however, setting PYTHONUNBUFFERED=NO did not help.

Also, when interacting with the python interpreter directly (i.e. not via telnet), no such error occurs.

My suspicion is that is has s.th. to do with the way telnet sends the line endings. Trying "toggle crlf" in the telnet session to switch from `<CR><NUL>` to `<CR><LF>` for the enter key did not help either, though.

Any help/ideas/thoughts are highly appreciated!

Cheers,
Carsten

Answer (score 2):

Found the reason myself, so for future searchers:

telnet automatically adds a CR after each command that is typed and sent with <enter>. However, the python interpreter does not accept the CR (\r) as part of the command and reports a syntax error on that character (\r is non-printable and hence probably invisible in the error message generated by python).
See also here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/855998

The solution for me was to communicate with a tool different from telnet: netcat in this case.

```
nc -v localhost 5092
```

opens a telnet-like session in which CR is not automatically added to the command. It works!

Comment: Yep, that sounds like a conflict between the telnet protocol (which is not straight up tcp), terminal layer and system newline representation. Python was operating with \n newlines, per POSIX conventions, but telnet sends \r\0. Normally the terminal layer telnetd uses handles this (compare stty) but you were connecting to socat instead, which makes no translation. Some other possible workarounds would be to have Python's sys.stdin in universal mode and use crlf mode in telnet, or just use socat or netcat instead of telnet.